# What's the canonical way of disallowing empty strings as values?

Tags: jsonschema

I have a number of string properties. How do I make sure those strings are not empty? Something more declarative than `minLength: 1`. Similar to `required` in HTML, whose somewhat equivalent for text inputs is `minlength=1`.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "^(?:num|str|text|check|bool)[1-3]$": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 50
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `minLength: 1` It expresses exactly what you need "a string that is not empty"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is in fact by using [minLength](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#length):

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "^(?:num|str|text|check|bool)[1-3]$": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 50
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

You can always use reusable subschemas with [$defs](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#defs) to create your own definition of an non-empty string. This also gives you a canonical and reusable name for it.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "^(?:num|str|text|check|bool)[1-3]$": {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/nonEmptyStringOfMaxSize"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "$defs": {
    "nonEmptyStringOfMaxSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 50
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have seen things like `#/definitions/nonEmptyString` and such. What are they and where do they come from?

Comment: I added an example above. Basically, what you can do in jsonschema is naming parts of your schema. This way you get reusability and can abstract away the actual rules and focus on the higher-level concepts, which gives you the names you were looking for (in the case above ``nonEmptyStringOfMaxSize``.